# Assign Value in List using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following classes:

```
public class ProviderQualificationTimeViewModel
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public List<ProviderQualificationDetail> ProviderQualificationDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderQualificationDetail
{
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string ProviderQualificationTime { get; set; }
    public string TotalServiceableOffers { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I want to create a new object if condition is true else I want to update `ProviderQualificationDetail.ProviderQualificationTime` where ProviderQualificationDetail.ProviderName == providerName
Is it possible using lambda expression?

```
List<ProviderQualificationDetail> providerQualificationDetail = new List<ProviderQualificationDetail>();

foreach (ProviderModel providers in allProviders)
{
    if(!providerQualificationDetail.Any(p=>p.ProviderName.Contains(providerName)))
    {
        ProviderQualificationDetail ProviderQualificationDetail = new ProviderQualificationDetail();
        ProviderQualificationDetail.ProviderName = providerName;
        ProviderQualificationDetail.ProviderQualificationTime = Math.Round(processingTime).ToString();
        ProviderQualificationDetail.TotalServiceableOffers = "Not serviceable";
        providerQualificationDetail.Add(ProviderQualificationDetail);
    }
    else
    {
        //Lambda expression here
    }
}
```

Comment: is that ProviderModel.providerName?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this in else part:

```
foreach (var item in providerQualificationDetail.Where(x => x.ProviderName== providerName))
{
item.ProviderQualificationTime = Math.Round(processingTime).ToString();
}
```

Or

```
providerQualificationDetail.Where(x => x.ProviderName == ProviderName).Select(c =>                      
{
c.ProviderQualificationTime = "new time ";
return providerQualificationDetail;
}).ToList();
```

Or

```
providerQualificationDetail.ForEach(x =>
{
if(x.ProviderName == ProviderName)
x.ProviderQualificationTime = "new time";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
List<ProviderQualificationDetail> providerQualificationDetail = new List<ProviderQualificationDetail>();

foreach (ProviderModel providers in allProviders)
{
    if(!providerQualificationDetail.Any(p=>p.ProviderName.Contains(providerName)))
    {
        ProviderQualificationDetail ProviderQualificationDetail = new ProviderQualificationDetail();
        ProviderQualificationDetail.ProviderName = providerName;
        ProviderQualificationDetail.ProviderQualificationTime = Math.Round(processingTime).ToString();
        ProviderQualificationDetail.TotalServiceableOffers = "Not serviceable";
        providerQualificationDetail.Add(ProviderQualificationDetail);
    }
    else
    {
var qualificationDetail = providerQualificationDetail.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProviderName.Equals(providerName));
//Assing your values here
//example; 
qualificationDetail.ProviderName = NewProviderName.ToString();
providerQualificationDetail.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```